# LyX new macros and instant preview

Tags: lyx

When we define new macros in LyX, can we still have instant preview for them?

For example, I defined a new command `\abc`, but when I put `\abc` in the math inset, it does not have instant preview. Though if I compile to a DVI, it's there in DVI.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome newuser! Could you fill out your question a bit more?  "Instant preview" sounds a bit like <a href="http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wysiwyg">WYSIWYG</a> but not sure in the context of macros.  What is it you want to do?  If you're asking for a feature to be added to LyX, though, you should <a href="http://www.lyx.org/trac/wiki/BugTrackerHome">contact the LyX developers</a>

Comment: @Matthew. By instant preview, I mean Tools->Preferences->Look&Feel->Display->Instant Preview. It's in the math inset. My problem is that, for example, I define a new command \abc, but when I put \abc in the math inset, it does not have instant preview. Though if I complie to a DVI, it's there in DVI.

Comment: Hm, that's strange, it works for me.  Can you give us more details? How exactly do you define `\abc`.  Do you get instant preview if you do not use user defined commands?

Comment: Hi, I get instant preview with ordinarty commands. And for example, I define $\newcommand{\abc}{A}$, then I put \abc in math inset, it does not show anything

Comment: @newuser You really should not define commands in the middle of your document this way.  LyX has no way of knowing you defined them, and cannot use them when generating the preview.  Either define all your commands in the document preamble, or use "insert->math->macro" to define new commands using LyX math macros.  Look at the "Math" section of LyX help menu for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Lyx is not WYSIWYG, because it does not make much effort to ensure that what it displays matches how it will be rendered as DVI or PDF.  In particular, it will render Tex code blocks as source in the Lyx editing window, and compile it normally using Latex when generating DVI/PDF.

Lyx does not keep track of definitions made in Tex code blocks or in the preamble.  If you want these to render in formulae, you have to define a [layout](http://wiki.lyx.org/Layouts/Layouts), which isn't really for beginners.

Comment: LyX does seem to be keeping track of the definitions made in the preamble.  You can also use math macros (Insert -> Math -> Macro), LyX does keep track of those.

Comment: @Jan: Lyx assembles a Latex text from its own representation, but the contents of the preamble and Tex code block are completely uninterpreted.  If one Tex block contains a `\newcommand` definition, Lyx won't know that it is related to a macro in another Tex block.  Lyx can't do "instant preview" with them.

Comment: @Charles: That's strange, when I test this, macros defined in the preamble do seem to be recognized in the preview.  Also, it does not seem like it would be difficult for LyX to use the preamble in instant preview, and it would, in my opinion, be quite desirable to do that, since in preamble, you can load packages unsupported by LyX, change fonts, etc, and LyX really should take these into account when generating previews.  And, at least on my computer, it does.

Comment: @Jan: I've tried this out: with `\newcommand{\five}{5}` in either the preamble or a Tex block, the control sequence `\five` renders as whitespace.  What do you mean by "macros defined in the preamble do seem to be recognized in the preview"?

Comment: @Charles: here, when I put it in the preamble (Document->Settings...->LaTeX Preamble), it renders fine in a preview.  If I include it in a ERT, it doesn't.  Which is exactly what I would expect. My LyX version is 1.6.7.

Comment: @Jan: Just to avoid risk of talking past each other, you mean the preview given when clicking away from a formula block containing `\five` as defined in the preamble?  I'm using Lyx 1.6.6, and that's not what I see.  The behaviour you see makes perfect sense: it's how Auctex's maths preview works.  I'll take another look at this tomorrow.

Comment: @Charles: Yes.  If I define a command in a preamble, or as a "Math macro", it works in the math preview.

Answer (score 2):

As commented by Jan Hlavacek, you can use "math macros (Insert -> Math -> Macro)" for instant view of custom latex commands (\newcommand).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/84148)

Comment: No. I believe Jan Hlavacek's comment is exactly what the user want. So it is better to repost it as a formal answer.